# Function onEdit's range object Event does not return the correct range when merged cells are included in the edited range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Reference sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WozsMdZGyWHYuLdyeXUZDpgv6ELxEG3urJTp2RAQUt0/edit?usp=sharing

I am using the following onEdit function to check for specific changes regarding a certain range of cells:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Add the target cell (the one where we will write the edited range) to a variable
  var cell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(11, 3, 1, 1);
  // Conditional to check if the edit isnt performed in the cell we will write the range to
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() != cell.getA1Notation()) {
    // Set the target cell value to the edited range in A1 notation
    cell.setValue(e.range.getA1Notation());
  };  
};
```

When the edited range does not include merged cells, this works fine. However, if there are merged cells included in the edited range, then the function returns a single cell as a range, and that cell is the first cell in the merged group, even if the edited range started in a column or a row before the merged group of cells.

This can be verified by editing the cells in B2:F8. At first, you can edit only non-merged cells, and after that you can edit a range that includes merged cells.

I expected the range object event to return the correct edited range instead of only the first cell of the merged group.

This unexpected behavious prevents me from adequately using the range for verifications in other functions.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the event object of OnEdit cannot be used for the merged ranges. So, in this case, it is required to prepare a script for using the merged ranges. In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range, source } = e;
  var cell = source.getActiveSheet().getRange(11, 3, 1, 1);
  var startRow1 = cell.getRow();
  var endRow1 = startRow1 + cell.getNumRows() - 1;
  var startColumn1 = cell.getColumn();
  var endColumn1 = startColumn1 + cell.getNumColumns() - 1;
  var editRanges = range.isPartOfMerge() ? range.getMergedRanges() : [range];
  var check = editRanges.some(r => {
    var startRow2 = r.getRow();
    var endRow2 = startRow2 + r.getNumRows() - 1;
    var startColumn2 = r.getColumn();
    var endColumn2 = startColumn2 + r.getNumColumns() - 1;
    return startRow2 >= startRow1 && endRow2 <= endRow1 && startColumn2 >= startColumn1 && endColumn2 <= endColumn1;
  });
  if (check) return;
  cell.setValue(editRanges.map(r => r.getA1Notation()).join(","));
}
```

- By this modification, for example, when the merged cell of "D6:E6" is edited, the edited range returns "D6:E6". And, when the cell "C11" is edited, no value is returned.

#### References:

- [isPartOfMerge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ispartofmerge)
- [getMergedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)